# Multiple Woocommerce Session with same cart id

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

We are currently having issues with the number of woocommerce session that are being stored in our db.

I have taken a look and have noticed we have a lot of sessions that contain the same hash.

[Multiple session example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDgdA.png)

I assume this is the cart id/hash.

I have been trying to find what action on our website could cause this to happen but have had no luck to recreate it on my local. Does anyone know when this could happen?

Is this normal behaviour for this session data? should this just be cleared by the cron job that checks there expiration date?

Comment: I think the duplicate hashes are the item hashes themselves. If you've ever tried to do things like removing items from a cart using PHP, you end up having to deal with item IDs that look similar to that. I'll see if I can find any documentation about that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not WooCommerce documentation, but it does look like it's the cart item ID that is the same. Take a look at this image.

[image: Screenshot of print_r]

That's the output when I did

```
global $woocommerce;
print_r($woocommerce->cart->get_cart());
```

Note the key of the first element in the array. Now, take a look at some data from the `woocommerce_sessions` table.

Here is data from one user:

```
a:19:{s:4:"cart";s:664:"a:2:{s:32:"41ae36ecb9b3eee609d05b90c14222fb";a:10:{s:10:"product_id";i:417;...
```

Here is data from another:

```
s:4:"cart";s:335:"a:1:{s:32:"41ae36ecb9b3eee609d05b90c14222fb";a:10:{s:10:"product_id";...
```

Both sessions contain that hash within their serialized data since it is the ID used for that item in the cart. It's fine for both sessions to contain this. The cart doesn't really have an ID itself, but the WooCommerce session does, and the `session_value` data is the contents of the cart, and some user data if the user is logged in.